# What does "struggle" mean here? Does it have a negative connotation or positive?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What's the meaning of 'struggle to tackle' in this sentence?

"How many of us struggle to tackle a problem or goal because it just seems beyond our capabilities to deal with."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to read in context

"Struggle" can mean "make a great effort", (this is generally the positive sense) It can also mean "have great difficulty" (in this sense it has a negative tone). 
It also has noun and verb senses, which overlap with the meanings above.

For example

> They struggled for years to achieve equality and civil rights.
>
> John is struggling in maths, and is unlikely to achieve a passing grade.

Looking at your example, the context gives "because it seems [too difficult]"  This must be the meaning "Have great difficulty". It implies that many people are unable to tackle these problems.

Finally "to tackle a problem" is to take action to deal with the problem.

> My bedroom is too cold. I'm going to tackle this problem by installing heaters.